# Performance regression when moving same application to different system

Tags: ubuntu, clang, performance-testing

I'm not sure my title is adequate without an explanation.

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04.1 using the clang-10 compiler.

My development system is an aging Intel® Core™ i7-3740QM CPU @ 2.70GHz × 8

My production system is an Intel i7-8700 CPU @ 3.2Ghz x 12

I have an application where I have made some optimizations and experienced a small percentage gain in performance on the development system when compared to the un-optimized code.

However when I transfer the binaries to the production system the un-optimized version is 20% faster than the optimized version.  (Both binaries are installed)

I located dead code that was no longer providing any useful function in the main loop and removed the code without loss of application functionality.

This loop is an intensive loop for a CPU emulator (so profiling shows extensive utilization).

So in summary removing this code allowed the application to perform 2% faster on the dev system but 20% slower on the production system. As the application has no I/O and is compute and memory bound my expectation is the code should be 2% faster on any system I drop it on.

I'm at a loss to explain this behavior or what I can do to identify the probable cause.

What I'm looking for is some guidance on how I can start to identify the performance regression on production system.

Comment: What is the application stack and are the run times exactly the same?

Comment: The run times of comparatively what exactly?  The run times for the non-optimized version behave as expected and are proportional to performance of the system they are running on.  It is only the optimized version that is behaving strangely on the higher performing i7-8700.  Otherwise I expect the run times to be different between an i7-3740 and an i7-8700!

Answer (score 0):

Without any further knowledge of either your application or any of the optimizations you did: looking at the datasheets of the respective CPUs the i7-3740QM seems to outdo the i7-8700 in terms of integrated GPU clock speed. Might it be the case that your optimizations make use of any GPU specific instructions?

Comment: The application doesn't use the GPU!  The specific optimization was to replace C if statements executed in the main emulation loop with C computed gotos.  Since the if conditions rarely change checking them every time in the loop was not very efficient.